# How to add a simple bar chart to bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

How can I add a [bar chart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple) to the Business button in the Bottom navigation bar from the following [flutter example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)? Do I need to create two different dart files under lib folder or I just add the charts in the main.dart file?

Tried

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            Stack(
              children:<Widget>[
                width:100,
                height:100,
                color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width:90,
                  height:90,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really add anything complex here with that example. You can use Stack under Icon and then add another widget i.e. containter with container child and fill it up the way you would like.

However, Flutter is really great when it comes to handling the screen.
You can simply create your own bottom navigation bar however you would like.
Simply pass widget to bottomNavigationBar and create it in any way you would like.

```
      Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
```

then you can create widget any way you normally do.

edited:

this would be exact solution :)

```
    BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Business',
          icon: Container(
            height: 32,
            width: 50,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Icon(Icons.business, size: 24),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 28,
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 28,
                child: Container(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          label: 'School',
        ),
      ]),
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean like this (I posted the code in the question)? That gave me errors.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html but it didn't work.

Comment: just copy and paste code from above the one from edited part.